# How do you sum a field and set the background color depending on the result in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

In an SSRS report, I have a single row that is totals.  Some fields are negative and some are positive.  Some are zero. I wish to be able to set the background color depending on the value. Red for <0, Green for >0 and no color for 0.

Also, I would like to show the absolute value, so no minus signs.  The color will determine if <0 or >0.

It looks like it might be something like this:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!OffenseCount.Value = 0), "No Color", IIF(Sum(Fields!OffenseCount.Value = 0) > 0, "Green", "Red"))
```

but I can't get it to work this way and this doesn't even address the Abs issue

If you could also point me to a good reference for formulating these expressions, that would also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't get that the IIF statement had to be in the fill color.  I thought it was in the expression for the cell.  Got that sorted out and everything else became easy. Hopefully, my ignorance and solution will help someone else.

Comment: Just as a note. You should use `Nothing` (no quotes - it's a keyword). instead of `"No Color"`. This will always give you the correct default value.